# How to Freeze/Lock android Camera X preview with Flash Light updates on taking picture?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camerax

I am implementing Camera X. The issue i am facing is to implement a mechanism to lock/freeze camera preview when picture is captured. Currently i have implement a workaround but it doesn't work well if the flash light is on while capturing. I get a frame from `previewView` (PreviewView) `previewView.getBitmap()` as before capturing the image and then display in an `captureImage` (ImageView). But the the freeze frame not show flash light update. My current code is below

```
    private void capturePhoto() {

        showProgress(true);

        // Get the Information to be used & stored with Image
        ContentValues contentValues = getImageSaveInfo();

        Uri externalUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions options = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions
                .Builder(getContentResolver(), externalUri, contentValues)
                .build();


        // Play the Capture Sound when a picture is captured.
        playCameraShutterSound();

        // Display current frame From Preview in ImageView.
        freezePreview(true);

        imageCapture.takePicture(options,
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults results) {

                        ToastUtility.successToast(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Photo Capture Successfully");

                        // Update Last Taken Image View with new Image

                        getLastTakenImage();

                        if (results.getSavedUri() != null) {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Image Saved At -> " + results.getSavedUri().toString());

                        }

                        showProgress(false);
                        freezePreview(false);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {

                        ToastUtility.errorToast(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Photo Couldn't Capture");

                        Log.d(TAG, "Image Capture Error -> " + exception.getMessage());

                        showProgress(false);
                        freezePreview(false);

                    }
                });

    }
```

```
    private void freezePreview(boolean value) {

        if (value) {

            Bitmap bitmap = mainBinding.previewView.getBitmap();

            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(bitmap).into(mainBinding.captureImage);

            mainBinding.captureImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mainBinding.previewView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else {

            mainBinding.previewView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mainBinding.captureImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The flash is triggered at some point after `takePicture()` is called, there isn't a callback for it in CameraX, so there isn't a direct way to know when it's fired.

You can instead use camera2 interop to indirectly check for the [flash state](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#FLASH_STATE). You can add a session [CaptureCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession) to ImageCapture's config, then  inside the callback's `onCaptureCompleted`, check if the flash state of the total result is [FIRED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#FLASH_STATE_FIRED).

```
// Override onCaptureCompleted to check for the flash state
CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback sessionCaptureCallback = //... ;

// Initialize an ImageCapture builder
ImageCapture.Builder configBuilder = new ImageCapture.Builder();

// Add the session CaptureCallback to it
new Camera2Interop.Extender<>(configBuilder)
    .setSessionCaptureCallback(sessionCaptureCallback);

// Build the ImageCapture use case
ImageCapture useCase = configBuilder.build();
```